# Write binary file in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a simple way to write binary data into binary file like we used to do in C/C++? For example, how can I create a 4-byte file with serialized 4-byte integer value without using fancy math?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I recently had a similar problem for work. I used the [BinData](http://bindata.rubyforge.org) gem and it worked a treat.
You just do something like:

```
File.open('test.bin', 'wb') {|file| BinData::Int32be.new(12345).write(file) }
```

and you don't need to remember any `Array#pack` codes.

Comment: the gem is doing the packing/unpacking for you. source code [here](https://github.com/dmendel/bindata). like the answer says, its just keeps you from having to remember how/which pack codes to use

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I believe it is easier and cleaner, even though requires an extra gem.

Answer (score 37):

You can use [Array#pack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#method-i-pack) and [String#unpack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#method-i-unpack) to convert to and from binary representations.  Combine them with [IO#write](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#method-i-write) and [IO#read](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#method-i-read), and away you go.

Comment: Yes, I think yours is the better answer for this particular question! +1

Comment: This seems like what I want to do, but I still don't know how to do it. What format should I unpack a binary string to using `String#unpack` ?

Answer (score 10):

There is [File#binwrite](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/IO.html#method-c-binwrite) to write binary data:

```rb
File.binwrite("test.bin", my_binary_data)
```

Comment: Better than the accepted answer and `File.open do`

Answer (score 3):

There are `Marshal.dump` and `Marshal.load` methods you can use.

Here's a link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization#Ruby.

And another that saves the data to a file: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/object_serialization.html.

Comment: This works ok, but I still couldn't get 4-byte file using this: File.open('test.bin', 'wb') {|file|  file << Marshal.dump(12345) }, I'm getting 6-byte file. The problem is that I need to create a binary file of proprietary format, this file consists of records, each of them is fixed-length C-style record with integers, bytes, etc.

Thanks for really quick answer though.

Comment: No worries. Pesto's answer looks very promising.

Answer (score -16):

In my humble oppinion, ruby wasn't made for such tasks. If you have to write to binary files a lot, it would be easiest to write some c functions for that and call them from ruby, which is quite easy using swig. I'm doing the same thing at the moment to write a raid simulator.

Comment: That's right - Ruby was meant for other stuff probably, but we have a pretty big Rails application already and we just faced this need to operate with binary files. Thanks for your answer though - we might consider writing the native extension in C/C++.

Comment: The problem with writing those functions in C/C++ is that doing so end up could tying them to a specific Ruby implementation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292610/what-version-of-ruby/3294275#3294275

Comment: As this question pops up as top google result when searching for "ruby write binary", and this answer is actually showed as relevant blurb directly in the search results: Ruby is perfectly fine for what OP laid out. Writing a C function, pulling in a whole new ecosystem (SWIG/C), possibly getting other devs on speed with C just to write some binary data would be hilariously complex compared to simply using the existing methods to work with binary data (see other answers).