# Ruby - remote file download ...timeout?

Tags: ruby, ssl, file-upload, download, stream

Excuse the tabs.  I'm trying to download a file from remote to local and I keep getting one back that is exactly 310 bytes (regardless of what file I choose to download).  I tried setting the timeout to 0, but this isn't working.  What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
        @downloadUrl = 'https://username:password@api.net'
        Net::HTTP.start(@downloadUrl) do |http|
            response = http.get('/file.ext')
            open('/Users/me/file.ext', "wb", :read_timeout=>0) do |file|
                file.write(response.body)
            end
        end
```

EDIT:  I don't want to use httpclient, I want to use standard net/http.  I am almost there, but I keep getting `initialize': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)` thrown at `Net::HTTP.start(url.path)`.  But when I remote "https", I get ECONNREFUSED.  ...Getting closer?

```
    url = URI.parse('https://api.net/file.ext') 
    @request = Net::HTTP.start(url.path)
    @request.basic_auth 'username', 'password'
    sock = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, 443)
    sock.use_ssl = true
    sock.ssl_version='SSLv3'
    sock.start do |http|
        response = http.get(@request)
            open('/Users/me/file.ext', "wb", :read_timeout=>0) do |file|
                file.write(response.body)
            end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using httpclient is much simpler when accessing via SSL.

`gem install httpclient`

I haven't tried this out, but this should work for you. Here is the [rdoc](http://rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.1.5.2/frames).

```
require 'httpclient'

domain    = "https://api.net/file.ext"
username  = "username"
password  = "password"

clnt = HTTPClient.new
clnt.set_auth(domain, username, password)

res = clnt.get_content(https_url)
```

You can refer to the ["writing a binary file in ruby"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941856/write-binary-file-in-ruby) question for saving your response to a file.

**Updated** Using net/http

You should be doing `Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port)` instead of `Net:HTTP.start(url.path)`. [See RDoc for Net::HTTP.start](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html#M001367).

```
url = URI.parse("https://api.net/file.ext")
download_file = opne("/Users/me/file.ext", "wb")
request = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port)

# .. set basic auth, verify peer etc

begin
  request.request_get(url.path) do |resp|
    resp.read_body { |segment| download_file.write(segment) }
  end
ensure
  download_file.close
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use the standard net:http if possible!  Updated code for current try (essentially the same new code works with get, post, delete ).