# How do i write a string containing an array of integers to a file as bytes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file-io, io, arrays

How do I write (raw) a binary string array representation to a file?

```
#str is a String not an Array
str = "[80, 75, 3, 4, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -74, 121, 57, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0]"

File.open('/Users/file.zip', "wb") do |file|
   file.write(str)
end
```

The code above does not work. How can I to fix it?

Comment: I guess this is what you're searching for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941856/write-binary-file-in-ruby (pack/unpack methods).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the answers here assume you are using an Array, not a String as you stated (and as your example shows). This should work with the String you showed in the example:

```
File.open('/Users/file.zip', "wb") { |f| f.write(JSON.parse(str).pack('C*')) }
```

Just make sure to `require 'json'`.

Comment: It would be safer to use `JSON.parse(str)` instead of `eval(str)` in case the string contains some dangerous code like `system('rm -rf /')` since this is a valid json representation of an array.

Comment: Thank you so much! Please update with JSON.parse(str) the main answer to save lives...

Answer (score 0):

`Array#pack` and `String#unpack` convert to binary strings and back. Use `IO#write` and `IO#read` for these strings.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want

```
str = "[80, 75, 3, 4, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -74, 121, 57, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
```

and not

```
str = [80, 75, 3, 4, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -74, 121, 57, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

About writing: `#write` calls `#to_s` which converts the array to its string represenation, which isn't what you want. To control that conversion, use [`Array#pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pack). Try `file.write(str.pack('C*'))`.

Comment: str is a String, so if i do that i get NoMethodError (undefined method `pack' for #<String:0x007f833ce472f0>):

Answer (score 0):

> It works, but i thought it was too dirty

```
str = "[80, 75, 3, 4, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -74, 121, 57, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
int_array = str.gsub('[', '').gsub(']', '').split(', ').collect{|i| i.to_i}
File.open('/Users/file.zip', "wb") do |file|
   file.write(int_array.pack('C*'))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why nobody mentioned string escapes. This works:

```
str = "\x50\x4B\x03\x04\x0A\0\0\0\0\0\xB6\x79\x39\x40\0\0\0\0"    
File.open('file.zip', "wb") { |file| file.write(str) }
```

Unfortunately there are no decimal escapes so you'll have to convert your numbers either to hexadecimal or to octal.