# How do I save a Net::BER::BerIdentifiedString as a binary file?

Tags: ruby, binary

Anyone know how to save a Net::BER::BerIdentifiedString as a binary
file?

I've tried .dump, but that did not work.  I noticed there's a .bytes
enumerator, but I'm not sure what to do with it.

Basically, I have an Net::BER::BerIdentifiedString [Binary Data] which
is holding a profile photo from an LDAP call, and I want to save it as a
jpg file.

Comment: You should check this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941856/write-binary-file-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I got this working by just writing the BerIndentified
String; not sure why it didn't work when I first tried it in Rails.

Anyway, here's the snippet:

```
ldap.search(:base => base, :filter => filter, :return_result => true) do |entry|
  [:thumbnailphoto, :jpegphoto, :photo].each do |photo_key|
    if entry.attribute_names.include?(photo_key)
      @ldap_photo = entry[photo_key][0]
      File.open(file_name, 'wb') { |f| f.write(@ldap_photo) }
      break
    end
  end
end
```