# putting a integer into a string in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to send a file on a socket, and need to pass its length in the first four bytes.

Here is what I want to do in C:

```
struct
{
  int lenght; //four bytes
  char msg[40];
}dataBuf;

write(fd, &databuf, sizeof(dataBuf))
```

How do I push an integer onto a socket, so it receives it as an integer at other end, not as an ASCII value?

I don't want to hardcode it like "`\x04\X03`" and I tried to do it with `pack(L*)`. That only works with array and I don't have a way to break my four byte integer into a four byte array.

Comment: Is this what you want to do?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941856/write-binary-file-in-ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting the integer into an array and then using [`pack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pack). For example:

```
socket.write( [0xffff].pack("L") )
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [BinData](http://bindata.rubyforge.org/) gem.

Your example might look like this:

```
class DataBuf < BinData::Record
  uint32 :length
  array :msg, :initial_length => 40 do
    uint8
  end
end

io = File.open(...)
r = DataBuf.read(io)
puts "Data buffer is #{r.length} length and it has '#{r.msg}' message"
```

I'm not sure about message, you should look at the String section of BinData documentation.