# Writing specific data types to pipe in Ruby

Tags: ruby

OK, last question from me - Let's assume I have the following data structure:

```
byte length
byte message_code
byte[] payload
```

it is very important that each bit of data be in it's correct data type when written to the pipe; how can I ensure that my data array (which in Ruby looks like this):

```
data = [ 15, 0, .... ] # the ... indicates the payload
```

is written as individual bytes - ie, 15 is written as a byte, not as two characters (ie, '1' and '5')?

Currently, my data is being converted to a string and then written, which means that 15 is not written as 15, but rather the individual characters for '1' and '5'. Which means that in the pipe, it is presented like this:

```
"1, 5, 0, 4, 1, 2, 1, 0, 4" (notice that the 1 is an individual character instead of being a part of 15)
```

instead of

```
150412104 (etc)
```

Thanks to Uri Agassi, my finished code looks like this:

```
data = [ 15, # message code + payload size
  0, # message code
  4, # protocol version
  12, # size of string
]

data.concat('hello, world'.bytes.to_a)
p data
packed_data = data.pack 'c*' # Convert the data into a string containing 8-bit unsigned characters
```

Comment: Please can you post a clear example of the input and the corresponding expected output?

Comment: Already did - the input is 15,0,4,12,104 (with each comma separation indicating a new byte) but the output is '1,5,0,4,1,2,1,0,4'

Comment: The input is an array, i.e. `[15,0,4,12,104]`, or a string? For this input the output you expect is `'1,5,0,4,1,2,1,0,4'`, `'15,0,4,12,104'` or `'150412104'`?

Comment: The input was an array, and I expected `15,0,4,12,104` in bytes, hwoever it was being written that each number was a string, so it ended up being `1,5,0,0,.....` instead of `15,0,4,12,104`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/941931/1120015) - use [Array#pack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002245) and [String#unpack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000775) to convert to and from binary representations.